# Find the closure of a subset in the sequence space.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
**Problem**

Let $\R^{\infty}$ be the subset of $\R^{\omega}$, which is defined to be the countable infinite cartesian product of $\R$ and $\R^{\infty}$ consists all sequences that are eventually zero, that is, all sequences $(x_1,x_2,...)$ such that $x_i\neq 0$ for only finitely many values of $i$. What is the closure of $\R^{\infty}$ in the product topology.

**Attempted solution**

[image]

**Question**

I think I have solved this one correctly. But could someone give me some pointers my style? I like to use $\implies$ sign for my proof rather than texts; however, in my last post in the forum, people criticized my style for not being clear. I looked over carefully and made some adjustments and implemented them in this proof. Can someone take a look at it and tell me if this proof is okay? Especially, is it legitimate to use $\implies$ in the way I presented?

Comment: @NormalHuman  Hi, thanks! I changed the title. Is it okay now?

Comment: This is a style issue. I use the implies informally but not otherwise.